# how to mass update a mongohq database with bcrypt pwds

Tags: mongodb, mongohq

I'd like to bcrypt all user pwds in a mongohq databse.  Is there a way I can execute this update on the database side for a mass update rather than connecting to the db from some application and running the update one by one?

Comment: Unless you were to implement your bcrypt algorithm in JavaScript I would say no.

Comment: if you are using blowfish more specifically you could add this: https://github.com/drench/blowfish.js/blob/master/blowfish.js to the system.js and then run a command in the console, that way it should be as close to the server as possible without the pains and troubles that would come with using actual server-side JS edit: or you can use: http://code.google.com/p/javascript-bcrypt/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update each one / user individually - this is the only way to guarentee consistency.

Comment: Yes, but can I do it db server side rather than doing it from an app?